# Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Laravel React JS

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-6

The application works completely, but the console returns this
The complete error is: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

My **backend** *laravel* returning:

```
return $customers = DB :: table ('customers')
    -> rightJoin ('debts', 'customers.id', '=', 'debts.customer')
    -> join ('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'debts.company')
    -> join ('addresses', 'addresses.id', '=', 'customers.address')
    -> join ('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'addresses.city')
    -> join ('states', 'states.id', '=', 'cities.state')
    -> select ('customers. *', 'debts.debt', 'companies.company', 'addresses.streetName', 'addresses.buildingNumber', 'cities.city', 'states.uf')
    -> get ();
```

My **frontend** *ReactJs*:

````
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class CustomersList extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      customers: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('/api/customers').then(response => {
      this.setState({
        customers: response.data
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { customers } = this.state
    customers.sort((a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0))

    console.log(customers)

    return (
       <div className='container py-4'>
        <div className='row justify-content-center'>
          <div className='col-md-8'>
            <div className='card'>
              <div className='card-header'>
                <h4 className='list-inline-item'>All customers</h4>
              </div>

              <div className='card-body'>
                <ul className='list-group list-group-flush'>
                  {customers.map(customer => (
                    <Link
                      className='list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'
                      to={`/customer/${customer.id}`}
                      key={customer.id}
                    >
                      {customer.name}
                    </Link>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomersList ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**React Keys**

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:

When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item `index` as a key as a last resort. 
For more clarification check https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

change this code

```
                {customers.map((customer,index) => (
                    <Link
                      className='list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'
                      to={`/customer/${customer.id}`}
                      key={index}
                    >
                      {customer.name}
                    </Link>
                  ))}
```

> May be your customer id is duplicating that's why you are getting warning.

Comment: I had tried something similar, but to no avail. Now everything worked out, thanks!

Comment: Thank you... I was having a similar problem. But this help

Answer (score 0):

In react when you map an array of elements it expects the each element to have a unique key which it uses to identify(and further diff etc) the elements so the error is because you have two elements whose key is turning out to be `1` somehow. so check why two customer elements has same `customer.id`. you can read more about why/how react uses keys in-depth here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: There are two id 1 lines because I have a RIGHT JOIN on my backend, this is completely normal. But I'm a newcomer to React and I didn't know that this was generating an error.

Comment: yes it does so try giving something else as key which is unique to every element